# (local variable) List holidays Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DateProject.Holiday>' to '?'

Tags: c#

This is the code I have below. It's for unit testing. I have an error for **Returns(holidays)**. It says "(local variable) List holidays Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DateProject.Holiday>' to '?'"

The error showed when I added "using System.Collections.Generic;"

```
[Fact]
public void WhatHolidaysAreOnThisDay_FindHolidays_ReturnsHolidays() {

    // Arrange

    var holidayProvider = new Mock<IHolidayProvider>();
    List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>() {
        new Holiday() {TheDate=new Date(2020, 6, 2), Name="Beach Day"},
        new Holiday() {TheDate= new Date(2020, 6, 2), Name = "Pizza Day"}
    };
    holidayProvider.Setup(m=> m.GetHolidays(2020)).Returns(holidays);  

    Date date = new Date(2020, 6, 2, holidayProvider.Object);

    // Act

    List<string> findHolidays = date.WhatHolidaysAreOnThisDay();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("Beach Day", findHolidays[0]);
    Assert.Equal("Pizza Day", findHolidays[1]);
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of `IHolidayProvider.GetHolidays(...)`?

Comment: @JackT.Spades good thing that someone upvoted post and hence whoever did that knows that and will edit post soon. At least we don't need to wait till OP sorts things out.

Comment: @JackT.Spades I'm still new to programming. What does signature mean?

Comment: @justabeginner01 it means the head of the method that defines what its name is, what argument types it has and what type it returns. For example, the function `int add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }` has the signature `int add(int a, int b)` (technically, the parameter names are irrelevant, what matters is the `(int, int)` part.